# Form field not updating to database Angular with mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am trying to create contact application where the user can save contact information to the database. Here the form data is not updating to database whereas if I use the postman to update data manually it is working fine. The delete function and get contacts functions are perfectly working fine. Only the problem is addContact().

However, I don't see any console error after pressing submit button.

I am using MongoDB as a database, nodejs as server side and angular2 as frontend interface.

`contact.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getContacts()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }

  addContact(newContact)
  {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','applicaiton/json');
    console.log("I am working fine");
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  deleteContact(id)
  {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact/'+id)
    .map(res=>res.json())
  }


}
```

contacts.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
  import {Contact} from '../contact';


  @Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
    providers:[ContactService]
  })
  export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact[];
  contact:Contact;
  first_name:string;
  last_name:string;
  phone: string;

    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {}

    addContact(){
        const newContact = {
            first_name: this.first_name,
            last_name : this.last_name,
            phone: this.phone
        }
        this.contactService.addContact(newContact)
        .subscribe(contact=>{this.contacts.push(contact);
       this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe( contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
        })

    }

    deleteContact(id:any){
        var contacts = this.contacts;
        this.contactService.deleteContact(id)
        .subscribe(data=>{
            if(data.n==1) {
                for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
                    if(contacts[i]._id == id) {
                        contacts.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.contactService.getContacts()
        .subscribe( contacts => 
            this.contacts = contacts);
    }

  }
```

contacts.component.html

```
    <div class="container">
    <h2 class="page-header">Add Contact</h2>
    <form (submit)="addContact()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-btn-success" value="Add Contact">
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-group -->

    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{contact.first_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{contact.last_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            {{contact.phone}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="button" (click)="deleteContact(contact._id)" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Please help me to debug my code.
Thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this line.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-btn-success" value="Add Contact">
 </div>
```

you need to put a handler on it so that angular knows you want to send the http call.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-btn-success" value="Add Contact" onSubmit($event)>
 </div>
```

then for onSubmit you can send the call with the event emitted.

Comment: It gives me error saying `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'onSubmit($event)' is not a valid attribute name.`